# Copy-SPActivitiesToWorkflowService : Scope '/SharePoint' was not found

Tags: workflow, powershell, error, patching

We are using SP2013 on-premise enterprise edition. Recently we patched our farm and receive this error:

Error UpgradeWorkflowServiceActivities. Run Copy-SPLocalActivitiesToWorkflowService manually to complete this action.

So I tried to fix it by the PowerShell according [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118439/sp2013-sp1-upgrade-and-workflow-servers/135343?noredirect=1#comment173729_135343).

I ran following:

```
$credential = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$site = Get-SPSite("https://sites.sharepoint.com/")
$proxy = Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy
$svcAddress = $proxy.GetWorkflowServiceAddress($site)
Copy-SPActivitiesToWorkflowService -WorkflowServiceAddress $svcAddress -Credential $credential -Force $true
```

I ran above script on SPWEB01 (we also have SPWEB02, SPAPP01, SPAPP02, two OWA server and 1 SQL) The last command return follow error:

> Copy-SPActivitiesToWorkflowService : Scope '/SharePoint' was not
>   found.  HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
>   f2122b2c-5f0b-4c58-a8d9-3bb283e39561. NodeId: SPAPP01. Scope:
>   /SharePoint. Client ActivityId : b69d9ccf-051f-48c7-8985-bdfe37d887c4.
>   At line:1 char:1

I have no clue what it means. Could I have your advice?

[UPDATE]: I found following in the upgrade error log. Seems related with the issue:

> SharePoint Foundation Upgrade UpgradeWorkflowServiceActivities
>   (15.0.6.0)    0   WARNING Error UpgradeWorkflowServiceActivities.  Run
>   Copy-SPLocalActivitiesToWorkflowService manually to complete this
>   action.  Error:
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowEndpointNotFoundException: Unable to
>   connect to the remote service at http://SPAPP01:12291/SharePoint/. See
>   InnerException for more details.

I can browse http://SPAPP01:12291/ but return 404 no found for http://SPAPP01:12291/SharePoint/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like at some point, you tried to configure Workflow Manager to work with SharePoint (so you can create/deploy/use *2013 mode* workflows). To do so, you set up Workflow Manager (a dedicated -free- product) and then connected SharePoint to it.

Workflow Manager generally sets up on `http://<WFserver>:12291/`, where *WFserver* is the Web server you install Workflow Manager on (could be a dedicated one, apart from SharePoint farm).
Once Workflow Manager is installed, on the SharePoint side (i.e. from any SP server), you run `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://WebAppUrl" -WorkflowHostUri "http://WFserver:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp`.

So, it seems to me that:

- Either you did configure Workflow Manager right, but after that the URL `http://<WFserver>:12291/SharePoint` (note however I doubt you did create it under `/SharePoint`) has been dropped for any reason.
- <del>Or you never actually installed Workflow Manager and someone only *tried* to do so, inexpertly, and only ran `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://sites.sharepoint.com"  -WorkflowHostUri "http://SPAPP01:12291/SharePoint" -AllowOAuthHttp`.</del> [actually not the case since you ping `http://SPAPP01:12291`]
- Or you did install Workflow Manager and someone registered a bad URL in SP, when running `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://sites.sharepoint.com" -WorkflowHostUri "http://SPAPP01:12291/SharePoint" -AllowOAuthHttp`.

IMO, the point is: if you never used *2013 mode* workflows and don't intend to use them, you need to remove that registration... I'll look now on how to do it.

**EDIT**
OK, so it looks like there's no way to *remove* the binding to Workflow Manager! See for instance https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7576a5a1-4774-4a29-9562-28ce1a26fb80/what-is-opposite-of-registerspworkflowservice?forum=sharepointadmin.
So, here are your options:

- Either remove completely the Workflow Service Application Proxy from CA (as suggested in the last post of mentioned MSDN forum).
- Or, as it looks like WF Manager *is* installed at `http://SPAPP01:12291`, re-run `Register-SPWorkflowService` with the `-force` parameter:
  `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://sites.sharepoint.com" -WorkflowHostUri "http://SPAPP01:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force`

Comment: I am sure workflow manager (2013 mode) is installed but no workflow is built on it yet. However I don't know the detail steps the guys had performed.

Comment: I suspect it was miss-configured. As you don't use 2013 WF, you never spoted the problem.

Comment: I checked the install manual. It mentioned wf manager should be installed on App server SPAPP01 but run `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://SPWEB01" -WorkflowHostUri " http://SPWEB01:12291"`. How can I verify the register value and correct it? I am not 100% he followed his install manual

Comment: The web application has an AAM `http://SPWEB01` when the farm and workflow manager was setup. Later it is changed to sites.sharepoint.com so workflow manager not work. So by follow your suggestion `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://sites.sharepoint.com" -WorkflowHostUri "http://SPAPP01:12291"` It is fixed. No need delete the proxy.

Comment: For future reference, I follow [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166284/how-to-check-which-value-was-used-for-workflowhosturi-with-register-spworkflowse), it return `https://sites.sharepoint.com/SharePoint`. So I think by default a "Scope" SharePoint will be added, although I don't have idea what is a "Scope".